# Contract with default function that uses more than 2,300 gas

Tags: testing, vulnerability

I'd like to make a smart contract that I can interact with that I can do two things with:

1. Be able to send Ether from it to a presale smart contract
2. Has a default function that uses more than 2,300 gas

I'm trying to make this as an attacker contract to test some vulnerabilities with https://github.com/MysteriumNetwork/Contracts/blob/master/Presale.sol, as I'd like to use it in the future for a presale as well.

This contract throws after a failed send on multiple occasions, with two of the occasions being open to draining of the smart contracts if the msg.sender has a default function using more than 2,300 gas.

I'd like to see if it's possible to make an attacker contract that can drain the presale contract and then test it out.

I know I can use:

```
function() payable { balances[msg.sender] += msg.value; }
```

as the attackers contract default function to have it use more than 2,300 gas, but I don't know how I can send Ether from the attacker contract to the presale contract, since you have to have a balance with the presale, and then be able to call the refund() function (where the main vulnerability lies) from the attacker contract.